# Unable to create an appium-android xpath using following-sibling and child

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

I want to create a xpath for UNLIMITED DATA with the help of `//android.widget.TextView[@text='Active']` xapth.

I have tried to locate the element using the below XPath using **following-sibling** and **child** but it didn’t work.

```
//android.widget.TextView[@text='Active']/following-sibling::androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/child::androidx.cardview.widget.CardView/child::android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'UNLIMITED Data')]
```

Please find the below image for your reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7q4a.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ7wm.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this XPath :

```
//android.widget.TextView[@text='Active']/following-sibling::androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView[1]//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'UNLIMITED Data')]
```